# oracle dbのリストア手順について

Tags: oracle

oracle dbのリストアについて、お聞かせください。上司より、リストア手順を月曜までに調査して、確立して欲しいと依頼がありました。
先週提示したところ、その手順ではDBは正常に起動しないとご指摘があり、再調査となりました。

以下手順を確認して頂き、ダメなところをお教え頂けませんでしょうか。
私自身、調べたりしましたが、わかりません。

［環境構成］
ノード:シングルインスタンス
バージョン:oracle db 11gR2
アーカイブログ運用:アーカイブログモード

［バックアップ要件］
日次バックアップ（夜間にdbを停止し、物理ファイルをバックアップしています。）

バックアップ対象は、データファイル、制御ファイル、redoログファイルです。

アーカイブログも取得しております。
※日次でコールドバックアップを取得しているのにも関わらず、アーカイブログも取得しています。こちらの意図はわかりません。わかる方ご教示ください。。

しかも、日次バックアップとは別に、制御ファイルとREDOログファイルも別途取得してます。
何故なのでしょうか。。

［リストア手順］

①DB停止
②取得したバックアップをリストア（物理ファイルをそのまま戻す）
※場合によっては、アーカイブログも
③DBをマウントまで起動
④recover databaseを実行し、リカバリ
⑤DBをオープン

なるべく早くのご回答をお待ちしております。
少ない情報ですが、宜しくお願いします。

以上になります。
お忙しい中恐縮ですが、宜しくお願いします

Comment: マルチポスト　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10170077710

Comment: 復元したい対象は日次バックアップ・REDOログどちらからですか？2つの違いの理解がないまま作業するのは危険では？